# Error: gas required exceeds allowance (10209310) or always failing transaction

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm newbie in ethereum and on my first lession I faced an issue that I can't solve:

Hello.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract HelloSol {
    uint savedValue;

    function setValue( uint newValue ) public {
        savedValue = newValue;
    }
    function getValue() public view returns( uint ) {
        return savedValue;
    }
}
```

This simple contract store and return unit value. It perfectly works in Remix.
After I compile this contract, I copy-pasyte WEB3DOPLOY to my private blockchain network, contract was deployed, I create an ABI and contract objects, after that I'm trying to interact with contract, "return" function works fine, but "set" fucntions isn't working at all:

```
> HelloSol.getValue()
0
> HelloSol.setValue(777, {from: "0xed4e9babb02cc48652375526bdb0d55a86d5c5ce"})
**Error: gas required exceeds allowance (6816018) or always failing transaction**
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I spend 12hrs trying to figure out the root cause but with no success. Any suggestions??
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you unlocked `0xed4e9babb02cc48652375526bdb0d55a86d5c5ce` on your private network's node?

Comment: Yes, sure I did

Comment: Do you have newer opcodes from constantinople, petersburg and istanbul enabled in the genesis file?

Comment: Ismael, I don't fully understand what do you mean, sorry. Here is my genesis.json - https://pastebin.com/w1mJT3ig

Comment: @kedcex use '@' to notify someone

Comment: @Ismael I don't fully understand what do you mean, sorry. Here is my genesis.json - pastebin.com/w1mJT3ig

Comment: @kedcex You have to explicitly enable newer opcodes since they are required by new versions of the solidity compiler.